# How to hide (mostly wrong) syntax errors in the structure view in the Delphi IDE

Tags: delphi-2009, delphi-xe5, delphi-ide

I really like using the structure view, but the many wrong syntax errors (meaning they are no errors) above them are often blocking my view. I always have to collapse them as they are initially extended. Don't get me wrong, I really like Delphi to tell me any mistakes, but these syntax errors are most times wrong errors, so there's no sense in paying them any attention.

I'd really like to completely remove this syntax errors listing from the structure view. How can this be done? I'm using Delphi 2009 in the moment but am using Delphi XE5 also sometimes, so hints for any version of the IDE are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off Error Insight, in the Tools->Options->Editor Options->Code Insight tab. Uncheck the "Error Insight" option toward the upper right corner.

Comment: I haven't thought of turning it off completely, but it makes absolutely sense. It could be a very good instrument, if it would work correctly, but it doesn't. So for now it's more confusing than helpful.

Comment: Just in case anybody else wonders: This needs a reboot of the IDE to work.